# .bat file not getting startup

Tags: windows, batch-file

1. I installed `elasticsearch` server in my local machine where I don't have administrator access. I try to open the batch file it runs successfully.
2. When I installed the same in a local server with `IIS`, where I have a administrator access too. I try to open the batch file it fails.

What is the reason for this?

My Batch file Contents:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL

if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto err

set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
for %%I in ("%SCRIPT_DIR%..") do set ES_HOME=%%~dpfI


REM ***** JAVA options *****

if "%ES_MIN_MEM%" == "" (
set ES_MIN_MEM=256m
)

if "%ES_MAX_MEM%" == "" (
set ES_MAX_MEM=1g
)

if NOT "%ES_HEAP_SIZE%" == "" (
set ES_MIN_MEM=%ES_HEAP_SIZE%
set ES_MAX_MEM=%ES_HEAP_SIZE%
)

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms%ES_MIN_MEM% -Xmx%ES_MAX_MEM%

if NOT "%ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE%" == "" (
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmn%ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE%
)

if NOT "%ES_DIRECT_SIZE%" == "" (
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=%ES_DIRECT_SIZE%
)

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xss256k

REM Enable aggressive optimizations in the JVM
REM    - Disabled by default as it might cause the JVM to crash
REM set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+AggressiveOpts

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseParNewGC
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

REM When running under Java 7
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseCondCardMark

REM GC logging options -- uncomment to enable
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+PrintGCDetails
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+PrintClassHistogram
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log

REM Causes the JVM to dump its heap on OutOfMemory.
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
REM The path to the heap dump location, note directory must exists and have enough
REM space for a full heap dump.
REM JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:HeapDumpPath=$ES_HOME/logs/heapdump.hprof

set ES_CLASSPATH=%ES_CLASSPATH%;%ES_HOME%/lib/elasticsearch-1.1.1.jar;%ES_HOME%/lib/*;%ES_HOME%/lib/sigar/*
set ES_PARAMS=-Delasticsearch -Des-foreground=yes -Des.path.home="%ES_HOME%"

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %ES_JAVA_OPTS% %ES_PARAMS% %* -cp "%ES_CLASSPATH%" "org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch"
goto finally


:err
echo JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!
pause


:finally

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on "it fails".

Comment: The command prompt opens for just a fraction of second and gets closed. So the thing is, its not getting started up.

Comment: Open `cmd` and run that batch file there. The window won't close, so you'll be able to read any error messages.

Comment: yes i tried with that too, It shows
`The system cannot find the file`

Comment: Could you please post BAT's contents on pastebin.com and link it here? Also, make sure it's not a shortcut.

Comment: @ gronostaj I pasted in my question itself

Comment: @gronostaj It's generally not a good idea to run random scripts unless you took the time to read through the whole thing first.

Comment: @Boomerang Remove `@echo off` and run the batch script from a command prompt. You should be able to pinpoint the problematic line this way.

Comment: @ekaj OP said he was running it successfully on another machine and he tried running it with double-click. If the script was malicious, the damage would have already been done and probably noticed.

Comment: @gronostaj You generally don't want people knowing if your script is malicious or not.

Comment: I failed to find the error, It runs in one machine and fails in another machine. Still couldnt figure out whats the problem.